# How to use intent in baseadapter class

Tags: android, custom-lists

Hi I have a base adapter class for custom listview. my listview has a button. when i press that button, I have to redirect the control to another activity. When I use Intent to redirect, It shows error during runtime. Here is my code,

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{

    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_elements, null);

    TextView textview1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    TextView textview2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    TextView textview3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView03);
    Button buy=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.buy_song_button);
    buy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent=new Intent(con,MainActivity.class);
        con.startActivity(intent);


        }
    }); }
```

How to redirect to another activity from my base adapter class?

Comment: whats logcat output ? error stack ?

Comment: 05-06 13:12:49.246: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1416): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Comment: you could use intent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); I know that doing this in an Adapter is not good practice, since u want ur adapter to only handle GUI related operations, but some1 can explain that much better than what I have stated

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have solved this problem myself. A simple modification in the Intent has solved it. 
I had to set flag to my intent. That's it.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
     {

convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_elements, null);

TextView textview1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
TextView textview2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
TextView textview3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView03);
Button buy=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.buy_song_button);
buy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent intent=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);


    }
}); }
```

Comment: where do you get your context object?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
  Intent intent=new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(),MyPlace.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra("city", "Yangon");
    activity.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use v.getContext() instead of con in onClick method

Comment: But this didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

this code worked for me, especially when you have base adapter class for gridview adapter :

```
cmnt_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.e("position",position+"");
                Intent comment_page=new Intent(view.getContext(),comments_page.class);
                comment_page.putExtra("position",position);
                view.getContext().startActivity(comment_page);
            }
```